# Best practice for realtime periodic task (< 1ms) with linux and multi core system

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, real-time, thread-priority

I am using a quad-core embedded computer with Linux as OS for controlling robot system.

Basically the project is multi-threaded, single-process program written in C++.
Here are some of the backgrounds and requirements;

- Some task (signal processing and communication with hardware) requires some what strict "real-time" operation.

  - Cycle period is 500us or 1000us (configurable)
  - The counter party of the operation is so-called 'hard real-time HW' (one with designated DSP)
  - Missing 1~2 cycle occasionally (may be due to jitter) will cause hardly noticeable degradation of system operation.
  - Missing 3~9 cycle occasionally will cause quite noticeable degradation of system performance but not fatal.
  - Missing >10 cycle at least once will cause whole system stop and considered fatal major malfunction.

The solution in my mind is combination of below.

- Put all the function required for 'real-time operation' in a single thread and make it 'real-time thread'.
- Put other functions in one or two threads and make it 'non-real-time threads'.
- Set `sched_priority` of the real-time thread around 95.
- Spare a CPU core for real-time operation by manipulating the CPU-affinity of all the default linux services to use 3 cores except 'real-time core' and set thread CPU affinity of the 'real-time thread' to use spared real-time core (so that critical tasks get minimum interference).
- Inter-thread communication will be done with `std::atomic` variables with memory order `release` and `acquire` but minimized.

Would it be a good practice for the application? Is there any other practice for more stable operation?

Comment: Have a look at Xenomai ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenomai ) as a solid way to get hard real-time scheduling on a Linux system.  Short of that, you can tell Linux not to schedule any processes on a core, and dedicate that core to running only your own real-time code; that approach seems to work, although it's a bit wasteful unless your realtime code was going to use approximately a full core's worth of CPU cycles anyway.

Comment: Getting interrupts out of the way may be prudent: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_real_time/7/html/tuning_guide/interrupt_and_process_binding

Comment: A dedicated DSP for the servo loop is more appropriate.

Comment: @ArminMontigny there are ways around the non-deterministic part of C++ - you can use custom allocators with all the STL containers, you can disable RTTI and exceptions. C++ is widely used for hard real-time programming, and it is fine as long as you're following a few simple rules.

Comment: @ArminMontigny I used C++ in HFT projects (with a couple of dozens of microseconds worst case latency), and in robotics (with 0.5ms refresh cycles), on MCUs (125us refresh cycle field-oriented control). It's ok. Surely there can be better languages, but there is no better language with such a wide range of supported hardware and such a rich tooling. Yes, I'd be glad to use, say, Rust in many such projects, or I'd use MISRA-C if certification was important (but that'd harm the development time quite a bit). Yet, C++ is a reasonable average default choice for a lot of hard real-time cases.

Answer (score 3):

If you need your 1ms periodic process to have a very low jitter, you simply cannot rely on the system timers. Xenomai or not, jitter will be significant.

The only reasonable method is to do the following (it's a typical approach in both robotics and low latency finanical applications):

- Isolate one CPU core (isolcpus=...)
- Build kernel with NOHZ_FULL support, set up nohz_full for the isolated CPU core
- Configure rcu_nocbs for this isolated core.
- Use `sched_setaffinity(...)` to bind your process to your chosen isolated CPU
- Use `sched_setscheduler(...)` to set `SCHED_FIFO` policy for this process (or any other real-time scheduling policy, it will tell the kernel to actually respec the NOHZ_FULL setting for this core).
- You must only have ONE process running on that core
- Do not use any system calls in that real-time process, system calls result in context switches and this is what you must avoid at all costs.
- Use busy wait - spin all the time you need to wait for an even or a time period. Do not use system calls for sleeping. Your CPU load must always stay at 100%
- Use lock-free communication between your real-time process and non-realtime supporting processes.
- Be mindful of the DDR latency
- Make sure that everything you do in your real-time process loop terminates before this 1ms timeout.

This way you will have a sub-microsecond jitter, as long as the other cores or devices in your system do not clog the bus too much.

Keep in mind that your I/O in this process must be entirely in user space. You should try to avoid using system calls to talk to the peripherals. It's possible in some cases if you can directly write to the control registers of the devices and use DMA to get the data out of them (i.e., just move the driver functionality from kernel to user space). More complicated if your peripherals rely on interrupts. An ideal implementation is if you're using an FPGA SoC (such as Xilinx Zynq UltraScale+, or Intel Cyclone V, etc.) - you can implement your own I/O peripherals that communicate via registers and DMA only and do not need interrupts.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed and professional recommendations. I will definitely try your solution, but I have one question. I used to have multi process project with IPCs  but now they are multi thread project with a number of inter-thread communication measure. So, does it must be single "PROCESS" or single THREAD" with CPU affinity is acceptable. Anyway the real-time task must communicate with non-realtime tasks some how, and if I go back to multi-PROCESS measure again, nothing but IPCs depending on system calls come up in my mind beside all the reworks and performance issues.

Comment: @chanwooahn cpu affinity works for threads as well. Even for inter-process communication, you can simply set up a shared memory  region (once, on startup) and then do all the same things you'd do with threads, use lock-free communication, atomics, etc. There is no need for system calls in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you again for the comment. One more question, you said one should avoid system call at all cost. Then how should one get the time? Timing is for sure essential part of real-time task. However, as far as I now std::chrono::high_resolution_clock may imply acquiring system clock. What do you recommend for timing? (My machine has ARM processor) Is there any good practice that works fine generally? Or is this highly HW dependent issue?

Comment: @chanwooahn it is hardware dependent, but at least on aarch64 Linux it does not need a system call.